# Adding more than one javascript image slider on same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want more than one image slider on same page with same class name using JavaScript. I have done for one image slider.

The issues are when I'm using more than one image slider it is not working properly.I  tried with childNodes also it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

And I'm trying to make sliding animation also(left and right) for that image slider.

If you need some more explanation, let me know.

I have given the code below;

HTML

```
<div class="container slider">
    <div class="slides">
        <img src="images-/b3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
        <img src="images-/b2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
        <img src="images-/b1.jpg">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="controlSlide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="controlSlide(1)">&#10095;</a> 
</div>  

<div class="container slider">
    <div class="slides">
        <img src="images-/b3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
        <img src="images-/b2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
        <img src="images-/b1.jpg">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="controlSlide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="controlSlide(1)">&#10095;</a> 
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.slides{
  position: relative;
  display:none;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.container  
{ 
  max-width: 100%; 
  position: relative; 
  margin: auto; 
}
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
} 
.prev{
  left: 2%;
  } 
.next{
  right: 2%;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
var position=[1,-1];
var slideIndex=0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() { 
    controlSlide(position[0]);
    setTimeout(showSlides,3000);
} 

function controlSlide(position) {
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex +=position;
    if (slideIndex>slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1; 
    }
    else if(slideIndex<=0){
        slideIndex=slides.length; 
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display= "block";
}
```

Comment: custom slider or plugin?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? There are loads of slider scripts out there.

Comment: i want custom slider only,  5 sections are there in single page. for all section should be as image slider this is what i'm trying. But  i'm struggling on how to trigger particular child class of parent class while click on the arrow of slider, Because i'm used same class for all. i searched a lot but i didnt get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you select all the slides at once, with document.getElementsByClassName("slides").

You want to alter you JS methods to work with the sorrounding element

```
<div class="container slider">
```

and then select and pass theese to controlSlide form showSlides. 
Not tested:

```
var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
var position=[1,-1];
var slideIndex=0;

sliders.forEach(function(slider){
    showSlides(slider);
})


function showSlides(slider) {
    let slides = slider.childNodes; 
    controlSlide(slides, position[0]);
    setTimeout(showSlides,3000);
} 

function controlSlide(slides, position) {
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex +=position;
    if (slideIndex>slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1; 
    }
    else if(slideIndex<=0){
        slideIndex=slides.length; 
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display= "block";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, still i'm not clear in  that code.  how the foreach function will work here? and  if i give childNodes its consider all the child classes which means taking anchor tag also and if i try with console for childnodes #text like this one childnodes is coming   . What is that #text ?  i cant find it.